# What is the cardinality of the class of $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

What is the cardinality of the class of $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$? In other words: what is the cardinality of the class of all rational Cauchy sequences that converge to $0$?

Answer (score 4):

**HINT:** If $q_n\to 0$, then given any infinite subset of $\Bbb N$, $A$, replacing $q_n$ for $n\in A$, with $0$ is again a Cauchy sequence converging to $0$.

Comment: i don't quite see where you're going with this...

Comment: @Mathematicxcz If you take for example $q_n=\frac1n$ (or any sequence of rational numbers convergent to 0 such that $q_n\ne0$), then Asaf's hint should help you show that there is at least $\mathfrak c=2^{\aleph_0}$ such sequences. (There is at least as many sequences in your equivalence class as the number of subsets of $\mathbb N$.) On the other hand, it is a standard exercise in cardinal arithmetic to show that the set of *all rational sequences* has cardinality $\mathfrak c$.

Comment: And maybe it is worth mentioning that the same argument works for real sequences (instead of rational sequences). See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218959/what-is-the-cardinality-of-the-set-of-all-sequences-in-mathbbr-converging-t).