# Ring of real-valued convergent sequences

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Here is a fun and challenging problem:

> Let $R$ denote the ring of real-valued convergent sequences and let
>   $S$ denote the ring of real-valued sequences. Prove or disprove that
>   $S\cong R$.

The cardinality of these two rings are the same (see Asaf's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218959/what-is-the-cardinality-of-the-set-of-all-sequences-in-mathbbr-converging-t)), but I somewhat doubt the existence of a bijection that would preserve the ring structure.

I would appreciate some hints.

**Source:** This is the last problem in [this homework sheet](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~jpbell/446Assign1.pdf) (as you see, the deadline is long past).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Recall that a ring element $r$ is *idempotent* if $r^2=r$.

The ring $R$ of convergent sequences has only countably many idempotents. For a sequence $(x_n)$ is idempotent precisely if any $x_i$ is $0$ or $1$. If the idempotent sequence $(x_n)$ converges, all but finitely many of the $x_i$ are $0$, or all but finitely many are $1$.

The ring $S$ of all sequences has uncountably many idempotents.

Thus $R$ and $S$ cannot be isomorphic.

**Remark:** The property of having only countably many idempotents is not expressible in the first-order language of rings. It would be interesting to know whether $R$ and $S$ are elementarily equivalent.